# CSS: is background-image working on <a> elements?

Tags: html, css

Is background-image working on `<a>` elements as well on all browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That [works](http://jsbin.com/ofato) for me on FF, Webkit (chrome + safari), IE and Opera.

Comment: I've actually realized that the <a> element disappear if there is nothing inside. In other words, I just want to use the image as button and I set width and height instead of inserting content. But it only works with div, the <a> disappear if they have nothing inside.

Comment: @Patrick: You will have to make the link block-level element first with `display:block` then you should be able to apply width as well as image.